# How to plot a parametric surface in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, surface

I have a parametric B-Spline surface, `S`

```
S=[x(:);y(:);z(:)];
```

Right now, I am plotting the surface by just plotting each column of `S` as a single point:

```
plot3(S(1,:),S(2,:),S(3,:),'.')
```

The result is this:

[image: S plotted as a collection of points]

Unfortunately, by plotting individual points, we lose the sense of depth and curvy-ness when we look at this picture.

Any ideas on how to implement `SURF` or `MESH` command for a parametric surface? These functions seem to require a matrix representing a `meshgrid` which I dont think I can use since the X x Y domain of `S` is not a quadrilateral. However, I like the lighting and color interpolation that can be conveniently included when using these functions, as this would fix the visualization problem shown in figure above.

I am open to any other suggestions as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your equations it's hard to offer an *exact* solution, but you can accomplish this by using [`fsurf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/fsurf.html) ([`ezsurf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/ezsurf.html) if you have an older version of MATLAB).

There are specific sections regarding [plotting parametric surfaces using `ezsurf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/ezsurf.html#bug9ock-1) and [`fsurf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/fsurf.html#bu5bawk-1)

```
syms s t
r = 2 + sin(7*s + 5*t);
x = r*cos(s)*sin(t);
y = r*sin(s)*sin(t);
z = r*cos(t);

fsurf(x, y, z, [0 2*pi 0 pi])   % or ezsurf(x, y, z, [0 2*pi 0 pi])
```

If you want to have a piece-wise function, you can either write a custom function

```
function result = xval(s)
    if s < 0.5
        result = 1 - 2*s;
    else
        result = 2 * x - 1;
    end
end
```

And pass a function handle to `fsurf`

```
fsurf(@xval, ...)
```

Or you can define `x` to be piece-wise using a little bit of manipulation of the function

```
x = (-1)^(s > 0.5) * (1 - 2*s)
```

Comment: Is it possible to define piecewise functions using `syms`? For example let's say `x=(1-2s)` for `s=0:.5` and `x=2s-1` for `s=.5:1`

Comment: @MikeJamesJohnson Updated with some options for piece-wise functions